# MySQL query - Date format?

Tags: mysql, date, netbeans

I have a few values to insert into a table but my dates are DD.MM.YYYY but MySQL is expecting YYYY-MM-DD.

I don't want to manually change all the dates, so how can I format it inside query?

Comment: MySQL's [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) --http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+str_to_date&submit=search

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I insert a date into mysql as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285231/how-do-i-insert-a-date-into-mysql-as-a-parameter)

Comment: you should use timestamps in your mysql database so you'll never have these format issues. you can get a timestamp in javascript with Date.getTime().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
SET datefield=STR_TO_DATE(<netbeansdate>,'%d.%m.%Y')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DATE_FORMAT?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

If you column is defined as a timestamp or datetime or date type, During your insert, just cast you value to a date VALUES(Date('mm.dd.yyyy'), xxx,xxx) ... and that should work