# What date_format is readable by mysql

Tags: php

What is the date_format that is read by a MySQL database? I got it to work before and now I just have no idea.

```
date_format($date, "Y M d H:i:s");
```

What would it be, written like that?

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285231/how-do-i-insert-a-date-into-mysql-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `-` between your dates and use `m` for months so it will be numerical. Normal format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
date_format($date, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be the following:

```
 date_format($date, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
```